# ScrollView not able to hold shapes

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview, shapes

I want to make a set of 200 shapes(Rectangles) in my activity
I made all the shapes but when i apply scrollView ,no rectangle is visible
.in my following code only 8-10 rectangles are visible
Please help me how can i add Scroll View in it

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context="com.android.shubham.muffinballgame.Levels">
 <!-- wanna add scroll view here-->
<com.android.shubham.muffinballgame.LevelDrawer
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and this is my java class of the view

```
public class LevelDrawer extends View
{
private ArrayList<Rect> button = new ArrayList<Rect>();
Rect rectangle;

public LevelDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    rectangle = new Rect();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint redpaint = new Paint();redpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    Paint whitepaint = new Paint();whitepaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    int x =0,y=0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <=200 ; i++){
        if (i%2==0)
        {x=0;y=y+200;}
        rectangle.set(x,y,x+150,y+150);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle,redpaint);
        x=x+200;
        button.add(rectangle);
    }

}
}
```

Any help is appreciated
Thankyou guys

Comment: what is the purpose of *button arraylist* it is private and also not used inside class

Comment: i am making 200 buttons so i need each rectangle and its bounds